# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: json, angular, codeigniter

Tengo un proyecto con angular 10 (frontend) y codeigniter 4 (backend), en Angular hago una consulta mediante un service y debo recibir una respuesta Json desde Codeigniter.

este es el código del componente

```
private loadData() {
    this.cargando = true;
    let doctor_id = this.apiService.tokenUser;

    this.pacientesService.getEstadisticas(doctor_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.estadisticas=data
      this.cargando = false;
    });
  }
```

este es el servicio

```
export class PacientesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  getQuery(query: string) {
    const url: string = `/backend/api/${query}`;
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url);
  }
 getEstadisticas(doctor_id: string) {
    return this.getQuery(`pacientes/estadisticas/${doctor_id}`);
  }
}
```

este es el código del Controller en Codeigniter que responde a esta consulta

```
public function estadisticas($id){

        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date1= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date))) . " 00:00:00";

        $builder=$this->db->table("nextconsulta");
        $builder->select("nextconsulta.*");
        $builder->join('relacion', 'relacion.idrelacion = nextconsulta.idrelacion','left');
        $builder->where('nextconsulta.nextconsulta >=', $date);
        $builder->where('nextconsulta.nextconsulta <=', $date1);
        $builder->where('relacion.doctor', $id);
        $consultaspendientes = $builder->countAllResults(false);

        $builder=$this->db->table("relacion");
        $builder->select("*");
        $builder->where('doctor', $id);
        $totalpacientes = $builder->countAllResults(false);

        $json_response = array(); //Create an array
        $row_array = array(
            'consultas'=>$consultaspendientes,
            'pacientes'=>$totalpacientes,
        );
        array_push($json_response, $row_array);

        return $this->response->setStatusCode( 200 )->setJSON( $json_response);
    }
```

Cuando hago la consulta con el navegador

obtengo la respuesta Json correcta

```
[
    {
        "consultas": 0,
        "pacientes": 2
    }
]
```

pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación obtengo este error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/backend/api/pacientes/estadisticas/365227eb8bcb2c5b9732b6c01d0ec5d8", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/a… with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/backend/api/pacientes/estadisticas/365227eb8bcb2c5b9732b6c01d0ec5d8"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

Dato curioso: Tengo el mismo código Codeigniter en 2 Hosting diferentes, en uno funciona todo ok y en el otro devuelve, el error.

Comment: Todo apunta a una advertencia de PHP (en HTML) que se ha enviado al navegador. ¿Podrías usar el inspector de red para ver qué contenido exacto te está entregando el servidor al navegador? Si no estás famirializado con el inspector de red házmelo saber para redactarte unas instrucciones básicas.

Comment: ¿Sigues con este problema o lo solucionaste?

Comment: @OscarGarcia no me permitía hacer mas comentarios, debía tener mas de 50 puntos,  te comento que el código estaba bien, resulta ser una configuración de uno de los hosting que respondía con ese error. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar con algun Bearer token. Logre que se pueda hacer el JSON.parse() usando doble comilla
por ejemplo:

```js
const example = '"<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/a… with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>"'; 


function parse(xml){
  return JSON.parse(xml); 
}


parse(example);
```

De esta manera JSON.parse() me funcionó

Comment: Agregar comillas dobles al interior de una cadena de caracteres no altera el funcionamiento de `JSON.parse()`, solo agrega un `\"` antes y después de la cadena interna. El código hará lo mismo a no ser que la parte que recibe esa cadena espera que ésta esté entre comillas dobles.